# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have a little login script.

```
function login($sql) {
try {                   
    $fbhost = "localhost";
    $fbname = "foodbank";
    $fbusername = "root";
    $fbpassword = "";
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$fbhost;dbname=$fbname",$fbusername,$fbpassword);
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $STH = $DBH->query($sql);       
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    session_start();        
    if ($row = $STH->fetch()) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = "$row[username]";
        header("Location:index.php");   
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

EDITS:

index.php

```
$sql = "SELECT username from users where username = ". $_POST['username'] ." AND password = ". $_POST['password'] ."";
login($sql);
```

Changed above from insert to select query. Now I get new error:
**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pvtpyro' in 'where clause'**

Comment: What are the value for $data and $sql ?

Comment: @Herode I added my code to the bottom

Comment: Please note the edit in my answer. Do not use the SELECT-query you provided since it's not safe from SQL injections.

Comment: You should really edit this post to remove the SQL injection encouraging statement as stef77 said, we don't want anyone looking for help to copy that and use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your latest edit: You can't fetch results with PDO after executing an INSERT query. See here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#105682

Edit: I suppose, since the function's called "login", you want to have something like this as $sql: "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = :username", and then iterate over the results with the while loop, and then log in the user if the password matches?

Edit2: Based on your edit to provide a SELECT query: **DO NOT USE THIS QUERY.** What you are doing is NOT SQL injection proof. Never ever use variables from user input (i.e. $_POST, $_GET et al) and put them unfiltered into an SQL query. Please look up the term "prepared statements" here at SO or Google.
As you can see, since you forgot to put single ticks (apostrophes) before and after the double quotes, MySQL thinks that your input refers to another column ("pvtpyro") instead of comparing the value in the column against a string. ALWAYS use the ":username", ":password" syntax (the one with prepended colons) or your queries will be unsafe and enormously dangerous to your application.

Comment: I meant to use "select." Weird now I don't know why that was working before. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome! I might as well add the hint that you should consider replacing the while Loop with a single ->fetch, since it's makes no sense to start the session multiple times and send the header Location more than once. Of course, there will arise no issues if username is unique in the database, but you should replace the while loop nevertheless to clarify your intention (you don't want to communicate "this logs in several users", I suppose).

Comment: @BrandiEvans are you submitting texts with `'` (appostrophe) in them

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of PDO uses 2 variables which are not defined in the code you supplied - $fbhost and $fbname.

EDIT:
You're calling `session_start()` inside the `while` loop, which can cause errors. Take it out of the loop.

EDIT 2:
You should really debug the code. Either via putting `die` in different parts of the code, outputting some helpful information just before (which is the less preferred way) OR by using xdebug and an IDE, which will allow you to run line by line, and see the exact state of each variable and such.

Comment: Oh I've never heard of xdebug. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If I undestand correctly, `$data` `$STH->execute($data);` should be an array, even if value is one. So, you may try replacing that query with `$STH->execute(array($data));`

**edited:**

Change your lines to this:

```
$data = array($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) value (?, ?)";


$STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);
$STH->execute($data);
```

Comment: The array is passed through the function

Comment: I changed my code above to show what's passing through. Should I still add the array if it's being passed that way?

Comment: Yes just to try it. And what is after `General error with` ? We need to see the full error code

Comment: That's it. That's all it says. Actually the "with" isn't even there.

Comment: adding the extra array gives me this error: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\foodbankdb.php on line 28
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Comment: Ok, Good. Meaning, the array is not matching your database field, so count them all

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you're not connected to your database properly... I had this error earlier today and it was for that reason. Either that or you have an incorrect string